# node.js how receive values from form

Tags: javascript, node.js

I create a server with node.js. Then I build an http form on the specific address. (I'm going do different forms on different addresses). 
I want to receive data from the user in specific field. (I'll give them different ID's).

But I can't receive it with `document.getElementById()` because DOM is undefined in node.js.

Can you advise a specific module for solving this problem, or some useful method?

```
var server = new http.Server(function(req, res){
if (req.url=='/') {
      res.statusCode=200;
      auth(res);
      res.end();
} else {
      res.statusCode=404;
      res.end("Page not found");
        }

})


function auth(res) {

     res.writeHead(200, {
         'Content-Type': 'text/html',

     });

     var body = '';

     body= '<form action="/" method="post">'+
         '<thead>Connection details </thead>' +
         '<br>'+
         '<textarea id ="text" name="text" rows="1" cols="50"></textarea><br>'+
         '<input value="localhost" id="host">Host</input><br>' +
         '<input value="root" id="user">User  </input><br>' +
         '<input value="********" id="pass">Pasword   </input><br>' +
         '<input type="submit" value="Connect" id="scheme"></input><br></body></html>'

     var toWrite =  header  + body;

     res.write(toWrite);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up as your project is now, you will receive the parameters from the `form` in `req.body`. I recommend looking into [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser), to parse incoming data.

Comment: Thanks.
And sorry for my terrible English.